# If n is irrational, then floor n + ceiling n is odd

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

If n is irrational, then $\lfloor n \rfloor + \lceil n \rceil$ is odd. By trying multiple irrational numbers i know this is True statement. But what would be the correct way to prove it?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which is it?  "$n$" or "$x$"?  Also, this statement is true for any non-integer, for instance, $1/2$.

Comment: Why don't you try to prove that, if $x$ is not an integer, then $\lceil x\rceil=\lfloor x\rfloor+1?$

Comment: Just notice that for non integer $n$ you have $m<n<m+1$ for some integer $m$. Then clearly $\lfloor n \rfloor + \lceil n \rceil = m+m+1 = 2m+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true for any (noninteger) real number.

Consider:

$$\lfloor x \rfloor + \lceil x \rceil$$

$$n+(n+1)$$

$$2n+1$$

and $2n+1$ is odd.

Proof:

Let there be two integers, $a$ and $b$ such that

$$a<x<b$$

As $x$ is non-integer real, it has numbers after the decimal point. Then, the maximum value of $a$ is $\lfloor x\rfloor$ (the integer part); if you add $1$ to it, you'll find $\lceil x\rceil$, the minimum value of $b$

Comment: So to clarify. If i pick irrational number (n) its floor is going to be n because its even. Then its ceiling is going to be n+1 which is odd. But if i pick pi then the floor is odd and ceiling is even. I'm a little lost.

Comment: @user3365751 Nobody (but you) said the floor is even. The floor is some integer $n.$ The ceiling is one more, it's $n+1$. Add them together, you get $n+n+1$ which is odd. Two $n$'s and a one.

Comment: @user3365751 in case of pi again there is one odd and one even which sums to odd

Answer (score 2):

For any non integer number one of floor n and ceiling n must be odd therefore sum is also odd

For any integer , both are same , therefore sum is even